# HQL and hasMany property

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have this objects:

```
class Employee {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String username
    String password
    String email
```

and:

```
class HappyHourGroup {

    enum EventEnum {
        HAPPY_HOUR, RESTAURANT_CLOSE, OTHER
    }

    String name
    Employee creator
    Date date
    Double recieveBack
    Double totalCost
    EventEnum event

    static hasMany = [employees: Employee]
```

I want to get for a given employee object, the latest group (date) he is in the employees of this group. I tried few HQL but it wasn't work at all.
what can I do to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need [many-to-many](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany) relation, so add

```
static hasMany = [groups: HappyHourGroup]
static belongTo = HappyHourGroup
```

to Employee. Note, that **belongTo** may go to **HappyHourGroup**? that depends on what cascade behaviour you want. 
To get the list of groups try this code:

```
Employee employee = employees.findBy.....
HappyHourGroup.withCriteria {
  employees {
    eq('id',employee)
  }
  maxResults(1)
  order("date", "desc")
}
```

See [criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for more info.